# I need to lock my headers so that no one can edit those columns but I want to enable autofilter on that using xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I need to apply protection on header rows of my spreadsheet but at the same time I want to enable autofilter.

I am able to apply protection based on the below code, but it disables autofilter too.

```
df.to_excel(writer_template, sheet_name='inputs')

worksheet = writer_template.sheets['inputs']

unlocked = workbook.add_format({'locked': False})
locked   = workbook.add_format({'locked': True})

worksheet.set_column('A:S', None, unlocked)

# Turn worksheet protection on.
worksheet.protect()
worksheet.set_row(0, None, locked)
worksheet.set_row(1, None, locked)

worksheet.autofilter('B2:I500')
```

My headers look like the below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel you can set the worksheet protection but allow the user to change individual elements such as autofilters. In XlsxWriter you can specify which worksheet elements you wish to protect by using the `options` argument in `protect()` (see the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-protect)).

For example:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                   'Data2': [11, 21, 31, 21, 15, 31, 45]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_filter.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', )

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

worksheet.protect(options={'autofilter': True})
worksheet.autofilter('A1:B8')

writer.save()
```

**Output:**

[image]